# setting ulimit in init script

Tags: server, ulimit, rabbitmq

I am trying to install rabbitmq-server on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

In /etc/default/rabbitmq-server it says:

```
# Maximum number of open file handles. This will need to be increased
# to handle many simultaneous connections. Refer to the system
# documentation for ulimit (in man bash) for more information.
#
ulimit -S -n 65536
```

(I raised the value to what the rabbitmq documentation suggests.) It makes no difference if I put the line in /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server instead.

Additionally, I have the following as the only entry in /etc/security/limits.conf (with an empty limits.d):

```
* hard nofile 65536
```

I can set my ulimit as a normal user:

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
$ ulimit -n 65536
$ ulimit -n
65536
```

But when I do `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`:

```
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server: 9: ulimit: error setting limit (Invalid argument)
```

I have restarted the machine to make sure it's not to do with my ssh session or anything like that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After writing all that, I tried setting an explicit limit for root in /etc/security/limits.conf, which solved the issue.

Had not expected root to be limited this way.